# Integrate Yii with Amazon web Services for video upload

Tags: yii

I want to integrate Yii with Amazon web Services for video uploading.
 Which one is more easy and fast to integrate?
 Yii extension like s3upload or any sdk or any third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Flysystem. It doesn't have Yii wrapper yet (I wrote one for a client yesterday, but haven't had a chance to open source it yet), butbit will give you a lot of control over file system writing without loving you in to one vendor ...